# search and replace string with backslash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a file which contains relative paths like so:

```
# source.txt
./somefile1
./somefile2
..
```

what id like to do is replace the `./` with the base dir like so:

```
# result.txt
/home/foo/bar/somefile1
/home/foo/bar/somefile2
```

`source.txt` has some 15 million entries and Id like to replace all the `./` at the start to have the base dir like the above.

Python would be too slow for this `.replace("./","/home/foo..")` and I am looking for a `sed` or `grep` solution.

Comment: You can use `sed -E "s/^\.\//\/home\/foo\/bar\//" source.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
$ sed "s@^\./@$/base/dir/@" file
# source.txt
/tmp/somefile1
/tmp/somefile2
```

To replace *in-line*:

```
sed -i "s@^\./@/base/dir/@" file
```

Comment: absolute genius stuff.. saved me those horrible python loops. Have a great day Sir.

Comment: done :) PS: I just replaced `$PWD` with my basedir. Might help newbies like me looking at this question

Comment: Does my edited post is correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code:

```bash
sed '/\./  s/\./\/home\/foo\/bar/g' source.txt
```